# Open a port on a google cloud instance without ssh access

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ufw, google-cloud

After enabling ufw on my google cloud instance running ubuntu, I can't ssh into the instance anymore. I didn't open nor close any port, I only ran: `ufw enable` and restarted the machine (ufw requires restart when enabled).

I have verified that the instance is running by pinging it.

Is there a way that I can open the port?

Comment: You could try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/918272/google-compute-ssh-port-22-blocked-by-ufw).